# Why is the signature of foldBack so much different from fold in F#?

Tags: f#

There are at least 2 things I don't understand about it:

- refactoring from left side to right side folding requires a lot of changes not only in signature but in every place depended on the folder function
- there is no way to chain it with regard to the list without flipping the parameters

`List.foldBack : ('T -> 'State -> 'State) -> 'T list -> 'State -> 'State`

`List.fold : ('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> 'T list -> 'State`

Any good reason for why would someone put all parameters in reverse in the signature of `foldBack` compared to `fold`?

Comment: To your edit: this just reads like a rant.  Also, it can never be changed without breaking huge chunks of code

Comment: I think the signature reads out naturally once you have the correct mental model of what each does. also in a lazy langage, there are very good reason to keep those guys separate. I think it is a valid question though.

Answer (score 16):

It's just a useful mnemonic to help the programmer remember how the list is iterated. Imagine your list is laid out with the beginning on the left and the end on the right. `fold` starts with an initial state on the left and accumulates state going to right. `foldBack` does the opposite, it starts with an initial state on the right and goes back over the list to the left.

This is definitely showing F#'s OCaml heritage as some other functional languages (Haskell, Scala, ML) keep the list as the last argument to allow for the more common partial application scenarios.

If I really needed a version of `foldBack` that looked exactly like `fold`, I would define my own helper function:

```
module List = 
  let foldBack' f acc lst =
    let flip f a b = f b a
    List.foldBack (flip f) lst acc
```

Comment: *keep the list as the last argument to allow for the more common partial application scenarios* well that's exactly not the case when it comes to foldBack in F#

Comment: Yes, that's what he said.

Answer (score 5):

It's a relic of F#'s beginnings in OCaml. You can see that the F# function signatures for `List.fold` and `List.foldBack` are the same in [the OCaml documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/libref/List.html) (where they are called `List.fold_left` and `List.fold_right`, respectively).