# Strange FSharpLint warning

Tags: f#

I am trying to reimplement the `List.distinct` function:

```
let inline distinct list =
    let folder curr = function
        | [] -> [curr]
        | l -> if List.contains curr l then l else curr :: l
    List.foldBack folder list []
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I got a lint warning that says

> `List.foldBack f x []` might be able to be refactored into `x`

However that doesn't make much sense to me as this leads me to return the original list without performing the distinct logic.

Is this a bug of FSharpLint?

Comment: Could be a bug. This would be a fairly reasonable if a bit bizarre message if it was a fold as opposed to foldback.

Comment: I must point out that this function most definitely doesn't do what you think it does. Start with the fact that both parameters of `folder` are lists, which then means that the parameter of `distinct` must be a list of lists.

Comment: @Fyodor I don't understand what you mean, as I have tried in FSI and the type of the function is `'a list -> 'a list where 'a : equality`. And with an input of `[1; 0; 0]` it gave me the correct output of `[1; 0]`. Did I copy something wrong?

Comment: I wrote the comment _before_ you replaced `curr = l` with `List.contains curr l`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently that's a wrong rule. Take a look at this excerpt from FSharpLint's [default configuration](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpLint/blob/e5b031b98a88720bae3a015823d620435817e77a/src/FSharpLint.Core/DefaultConfiguration.FSharpLint#L95-L98):

```
List.fold f x [] ===> x
Array.fold f x [||] ===> x
List.foldBack f x [] ===> x
Array.foldBack f x [||] ===> x
```

It's the same for `fold` and `foldback` here, so it doesn't follow the differences in signatures between the two.

The order of initial state and collection arguments should be flipped, see the ["mnemonic" approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074422/why-is-the-signature-of-foldback-so-much-different-from-fold-in-f) used in `foldback` definition.

Comment: Thanks. I have sent a [PR to FSharLint](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpLint/pull/190) to fix this.